# iMac crashes after upgrade to OS X Mavericks

Tags: imac

We have an iMac and after upgrading to OS X Mavericks. We have been been experiencing random shutdowns - below is the error report. I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to stop this from happening.

```
Anonymous UUID:       1A528784-6B8A-04A3-E8F5-8C113FFBBA4A

Fri Nov  1 13:48:49 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80218dc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa24a692c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000038250c8b4885, CR3: 0x00000000244b7000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x000038250c8b4865, RBX: 0xffffff805b9ca100, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x7fffffffffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff81f390b8d0, RBP: 0xffffff81f390b910, RSI: 0x0000000000000050, RDI: 0xffffff80218f36a0
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000e30000, R11: 0x0000000000070000
R12: 0xffffff80218f36a0, R13: 0x0000000000000037, R14: 0x0000000080000000, R15: 0x000000000000000c
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7fa24a692c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000038250c8b4885, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f390b560 : 0xffffff8021822f69 
0xffffff81f390b5e0 : 0xffffff80218dc19e 
0xffffff81f390b7b0 : 0xffffff80218f3606 
0xffffff81f390b7d0 : 0xffffff7fa24a692c 
0xffffff81f390b910 : 0xffffff7fa24a41ae 
0xffffff81f390b970 : 0xffffff7fa3e353a5 
0xffffff81f390b9e0 : 0xffffff7fa24ab265 
0xffffff81f390ba60 : 0xffffff7fa24ae087 
0xffffff81f390baa0 : 0xffffff7fa24ad74b 
0xffffff81f390baf0 : 0xffffff7fa24acc75 
0xffffff81f390bb30 : 0xffffff7fa24ab900 
0xffffff81f390bb70 : 0xffffff7fa249c8a0 
0xffffff81f390bbb0 : 0xffffff7fa24920fe 
0xffffff81f390bc00 : 0xffffff7fa2495d54 
0xffffff81f390bc50 : 0xffffff7fa2494a38 
0xffffff81f390bda0 : 0xffffff7fa2487176 
0xffffff81f390be30 : 0xffffff7fa2485c8d 
0xffffff81f390be70 : 0xffffff7fa3307e07 
0xffffff81f390bed0 : 0xffffff7fa2509b07 
0xffffff81f390bf00 : 0xffffff7fa250787a 
0xffffff81f390bf20 : 0xffffff802184a15a 
0xffffff81f390bfb0 : 0xffffff80218d6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000->0xffffff7fa24f2fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore(28.30)[558B2575-5197-3C4C-BAD2-8CB465638FA8]@0xffffff7fa2476000
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver(650.4.4)[B79A7E01-DD3F-3C1A-840A-879D262C69DE]@0xffffff7fa2506000->0xffffff7fa250efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(650.4.4)[972D3024-AF9C-3E09-A9EC-D9AB2A559B38]@0xffffff7fa1e15000
         com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard(170.15)[A652B17A-7312-32D1-A21E-F6B0B5D806C8]@0xffffff7fa3307000->0xffffff7fa330afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard(170.15)[0B7FA1C7-7326-3FB7-AF41-8905C145951E]@0xffffff7fa2f9a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver(650.4.4)[B79A7E01-DD3F-3C1A-840A-879D262C69DE]@0xffffff7fa2506000
         com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver(1.0.1)[00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]@0xffffff7fa3e34000->0xffffff7fa3e37fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13A603

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000021600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8021800000
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 64459827210981
last loaded kext at 58905458751175: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7fa3e38000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 58983181158393: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7fa3e38000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver    1.0.1
com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver  1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.12
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   360.8.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.0.10
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.7.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.3f17
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.2.1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.1.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    170.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Reverted back to Mountain Lion and it hasn't come back so far. Found any solutions for this? P.S., I'm suspecting those VirtualBox kernel modules, and that it has something to do with ACPI, but I'm not sure. Haven't been able to reliably confirm this.

Comment: I have the same issue. Whole OS crash and restart while typing. Happened from time to time. not application-specific. In my case, no virtual box info is logged, but I'm suspicious of Spector, which is a activity monitor software. Will try to get support from that software company and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Spector is the cause. See the crash report you attached, the backtrace section:

```
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000->0xffffff7fa24f2fff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore(28.30)[558B2575-5197-3C4C-BAD2-8CB465638FA8]@0xffffff7fa2476000
     com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver(650.4.4)[B79A7E01-DD3F-3C1A-840A-879D262C69DE]@0xffffff7fa2506000->0xffffff7fa250efff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(650.4.4)[972D3024-AF9C-3E09-A9EC-D9AB2A559B38]@0xffffff7fa1e15000
     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard(170.15)[A652B17A-7312-32D1-A21E-F6B0B5D806C8]@0xffffff7fa3307000->0xffffff7fa330afff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard(170.15)[0B7FA1C7-7326-3FB7-AF41-8905C145951E]@0xffffff7fa2f9a000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver(650.4.4)[B79A7E01-DD3F-3C1A-840A-879D262C69DE]@0xffffff7fa2506000
     com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver(1.0.1)[00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]@0xffffff7fa3e34000->0xffffff7fa3e37fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa2481000
```

System is crashing on this thread: com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver, which is a spector's thread.

Asked Spector's support team for suggestions with our Spector admin guy, and they sent us a updated version and everything is fine now.

So you should work with your company's IT department to get the Spector updated.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, a problem with a previous version of OS X (I think it was 10.7 Lion) was that VirtualBox would cause kernel panics. I think that's when it was in use though.

You may want to try unloading the kexts or maybe even uninstalling VirtualBox altogether to see if that solves your issue though.

You can unload the kexts if you want by running these commands:

`sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB`

`sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv`

It will prompt you for your admin password since sudo is used. There shouldn't be any errors, but if there are, let me know and I'll try to help.

Be advised, this may break VirtualBox. This is just a temporary testing solution. If you find VirtualBox to not be the cause of the problem, or you want to re-enable the kexts for some other reason, simply replace `kextunload` with `kextload` in the above commands. It does what it sounds like it would do. Loads them instead of unloading them.

If you don't have any more kernel panics (crashes) after this, then VirtualBox was likely the culprit. If not, say something anyways. Maybe I or someone else will be able to further help you.