# Upgrade from OS X 10.7.5 to 10.9.1 has caused my Macbook Pro to crash regularly

Tags: macos, restart

I have Macbook Pro (mid 2009, core 2 duo 2.53 GHz, 4 GB RAM), which I updated to OS X 10.9.1 yesterday. Since I have updated it, I have had it crash about every ten minutes.

Here is an error report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       2CB0D1D6-E70B-5C3A-5F04-ADBD8B7AEE12

Sun Dec 22 15:05:15 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8013edc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f94fd092c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000038250c8b4885, CR3: 0x0000000016b73000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x000038250c8b4865, RBX: 0xffffff8027488980, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x7fffffffffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff80a27eb720, RBP: 0xffffff80a27eb760, RSI: 0x0000000000000050, RDI: 0xffffff8013ef36a0
R8:  0x0000000000000045, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000080045, R11: 0x0000000000070000
R12: 0xffffff8013ef36a0, R13: 0x000000000000000e, R14: 0x0000000080010000, R15: 0x000000000000000a
RFL: 0x0000000000210286, RIP: 0xffffff7f94fd092c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x000038250c8b4885, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a27eb3b0 : 0xffffff8013e22f69 
0xffffff80a27eb430 : 0xffffff8013edc19e 
0xffffff80a27eb600 : 0xffffff8013ef3606 
0xffffff80a27eb620 : 0xffffff7f94fd092c 
0xffffff80a27eb760 : 0xffffff7f94fce1ae 
0xffffff80a27eb7c0 : 0xffffff7f961473d1 
0xffffff80a27eb830 : 0xffffff7f94fd5265 
0xffffff80a27eb8b0 : 0xffffff7f94fd8289 
0xffffff80a27eb930 : 0xffffff7f94fd7710 
0xffffff80a27eb980 : 0xffffff7f94fd6c75 
0xffffff80a27eb9c0 : 0xffffff7f94fd5900 
0xffffff80a27eba00 : 0xffffff7f94fc68a0 
0xffffff80a27eba40 : 0xffffff7f94fbc0fe 
0xffffff80a27eba90 : 0xffffff7f94fbfd54 
0xffffff80a27ebae0 : 0xffffff7f94fbea38 
0xffffff80a27ebc30 : 0xffffff7f94fb1176 
0xffffff80a27ebcc0 : 0xffffff7f94fafc8d 
0xffffff80a27ebd00 : 0xffffff7f9616349f 
0xffffff80a27ebd60 : 0xffffff7f961554e0 
0xffffff80a27ebda0 : 0xffffff7f953d3116 
0xffffff80a27ebde0 : 0xffffff7f953d31d3 
0xffffff80a27ebdf0 : 0xffffff7f953cdeeb 
0xffffff80a27ebe20 : 0xffffff7f953cde65 
0xffffff80a27ebe60 : 0xffffff7f953ad3fd 
0xffffff80a27ebeb0 : 0xffffff7f953a4a58 
0xffffff80a27ebee0 : 0xffffff7f953a49ef 
0xffffff80a27ebef0 : 0xffffff7f953a2e29 
0xffffff80a27ebf30 : 0xffffff7f953e1e17 
0xffffff80a27ebf50 : 0xffffff7f953e1dc6 
0xffffff80a27ebf70 : 0xffffff7f953e1e3c 
0xffffff80a27ebf90 : 0xffffff7f953e1f30 
0xffffff80a27ebfb0 : 0xffffff8013ed6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7f94fab000->0xffffff7f9501cfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore(28.30)[558B2575-5197-3C4C-BAD2-8CB465638FA8]@0xffffff7f94fa0000
         com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily(4.2f6)[7354BB5B-1D58-3330-9983-F09F59D1346D]@0xffffff7f9539d000->0xffffff7f95439fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(650.4.4)[972D3024-AF9C-3E09-A9EC-D9AB2A559B38]@0xffffff7f94ed7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(21)[C9064240-B311-3D2F-BAC6-0C90078E2DC5]@0xffffff7f95242000
         com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver(1.0.1)[00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]@0xffffff7f96146000->0xffffff7f96149fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7f94fab000
         com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver(4.2f6)[BDBCA485-A5D3-3EE0-A782-60D83447BAEB]@0xffffff7f96150000->0xffffff7f96161fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7f94fab000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily(4.2.0f6)[7354BB5B-1D58-3330-9983-F09F59D1346D]@0xffffff7f9539d000
         com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard(170.15)[99F55D7D-FD75-3745-A5C8-35367290C962]@0xffffff7f96162000->0xffffff7f96166fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7f94fab000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard(170.15)[0B7FA1C7-7326-3FB7-AF41-8905C145951E]@0xffffff7f9614a000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver(4.2.0f6)[BDBCA485-A5D3-3EE0-A782-60D83447BAEB]@0xffffff7f96150000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013e00000
System model name: MacBookPro5,4 (Mac-F22587A1)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5587474429491
last loaded kext at 2912183959043: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard   170.15 (addr 0xffffff7f96162000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 4501603906949: com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver 1 (addr 0xffffff7f96140000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver    1.0.1
com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver  1
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.15
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Unable to gather system configuration information.Model: MacBookPro5,4, BootROM MBP53.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.53 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.49f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334548312D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334548312D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: FUJITSU MJA2250BH FFS G1, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

If I don't use the keyboard then it will go longer without crashing.

Comment: Have you gone through the initial steps to rule out some common causes of the panic? http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Spector` is main the culprit of your issues (which is a keylogger). The bluetooth keyboard might contribute to it somehow perhaps, although it's likely not the root or underlying reason your system is having kernel panics. The backtrace tells us some of the story along with the last loaded/unloaded kexts:

```
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore(28.30)
         com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily(4.2f6)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(650.4.4)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(21)
         com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver(1.0.1)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)
         com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver(4.2f6)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily(4.2.0f6)
         com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard(170.15)
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard(170.15)
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver(4.2.0f6)

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5587474429491
last loaded kext at 2912183959043: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard   170.15 (addr 0xffffff7f96162000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 4501603906949: com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver 1 (addr 0xffffff7f96140000, size 24576)

loaded kexts:
com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver    1.0.1
com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver  1
...
```

You'll need to contact the developers and get an updated version (if you enjoy using keyloggers). [This question looks eerily familiar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107946/imac-crashes-after-upgrade-to-os-x-mavericks)... in fact it's nearly identical.

Comment: How would I go about uninstalling Spectator?

Comment: @BenLindstrom — You would need to remove `com.spsys.driver.IOKitDriver`, and
`com.spsys.driver.NKEDriver`, or do a fresh install of OS X. If you need to know how to uninstall it you'll need to ask in a new question; you should mark this one as answered.